# Help, I've screwed up. Wrong Libc6 install

Tags: linux, debian

I think I might have forcefully installed the unstable Libc6 on my Debian 11-based Linux distribution, and none of the `--fix-broken` commands are working.

Have I permanently damaged my system, or is there a way to recover?

Error log upon `apt install -f`:

[image]

I have absolutely no clue what to do with this. I am unable to update or install any packages.

`apt policy libc6` shows

```
libc6:
  Installed: 2.36-9
  Candidate: 2.36-9
  Version table:
 *** 2.36-9 100
         50 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.31+deb11u6 600
        600 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot lts/main amd64 Packages
        600 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot parrot/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the text, instead of adding screenshots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to re-install the Parrot version of the package:

```
sudo apt reinstall libc6=2.31-13+deb11u6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to "install" any package, you could get (download) the "libc6=2.31-13+deb11u6.deb" package and uncompress the content: each files on the corresponded folder. Also check permissions ;-)